# Debug prebuilt native library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gdb, native

I have an Android project using Gradle in Android Studio.
Also there is a huge C library which builds separately and then only binaries are copied to the libs directory.
Please give any tips how to debug native code in this situation. I spent a lot of time trying to find answer in the Internet but didn't find what I need.